# CSS Click driven animation doesn't re-run in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

Here's an example of how I'm trying to use CSS animations. I've had the same experience with all uses of animations in Chrome (but they seem to work ok in Firefox). Where on the first time the user performs an action which drives an animation, it runs fine. On subsequent times, it doesn't run at all. I've tried various ways of writing the `animation` line to try to get it to work.

Am I missing something? Is it a bug (or for some reason a feature) in Chrome? It seems like a pretty common use case, but I haven't found a good answer searching.

```
@keyframes menu-animation {
  0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform-origin: top right;
      transform: translateY(-16px) scaleY(.9);
  }
}

details:not([open]) details-menu {
  animation-name: none;
}

details[open] > div {
 animation: 300ms ease-out 0s 1 normal backwards running menu-animation;
}
```

```
<details>
 <summary>This is summary</summary>
 <div>This is hidden content</div>
</details>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@keyframes menu-animation {
  0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform-origin: top right;
      transform: translateY(-16px) scaleY(.9);
  }
}

details:not([open]) details-menu {
  animation: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: translateY(-16px) scaleY(.9);
}

details[open] > div {
 animation: 300ms ease-out 0s 1 normal backwards running menu-animation;
}
```

This should effectively reset the animation, and set all elements back to their oriignal state. I'm assuming you didn't forget to add the 100% keyframe in the animation, and you just cut it off because it isn't relevant. I can't test if my solution works, since you haven't shared enough code, but I believe that's what's wrong. Have fun!

Comment: Your solution works for 1 or 2 times. But if i will click more then 2 it will not generate any animation but then again it will. Check with multiple clicks.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tettoffensive/pen/NWEbgoo It seems to be working here after multiple clicks.